# Thunderbird does not show Calendar

Tags: thunderbird

I do not see Calendar tab in Thunderbird at all.
I tried v8 and v10 beta but same issue. Please help resolve.

I have installed all addons as well, it was working for me when I was using TB 5.

[image: Image showing no Calendar in New option]

<sup>Click to open a full-resolution image.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well found the problem or atleast it is fixed now, installed xul-ext-lightning package and now things are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You do have the correct Lightning Add on installed? For Thunderbird 8 this would be 1.0 which would not work in 10beta I believe.

Comment: I have installed all the right lightning addons, and it doesn't complain saying it has compatibility issues. I did install the required lightning versions for each 8 and 10 but nothing :(